# c# Winforms how to name a DataSource with a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, datasource

I want to control my databindings via a string or variable, where the text contained inside that string matches the name of a table in my dataset. Is there any way to use the text contained inside a string, or even any other variable type, as a part of the BindingSource name? Below is sort of what I'm thinking should be possible but I'm not sure if it is.

```
this.[string]BindingSource.EndEdit; 
txtbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", [string]BindingSource, "Column");

this."string.Text"BindingSource.EndEdit; 
txtbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", "string.Text"BindingSource, "Column");
```

Comment: Look into `Dictionary<K, T>` e.g. `Dictionary<string, BindingSource>`

Comment: @ASh `BindingSource`  is a table in a mySQL database. It is contained in the form's dataset. I have a series of tables that I would like to be able to move through, depending on user input. Instead of and extremely bloated `if` method, I would just like to use a variable. Can you point me towards some documentation for those other ways?

Comment: @TaW I will definitely look into `Dictionary` thank you

Comment: @CharlieFallon, DataSet class has `Tables` property with string indexer  `aDataSet.Tables[varTableName]` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58st33fb(v=vs.110).aspx. It is a key-value relationship, other classes (Dictionary) support it as well